# PHP SimpleHTMLDom & Php PThreads - Find not finding?

Tags: php, pthreads, simple-html-dom

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this,

This is launched within a 'worker' thread of php pthreads package.

I load a page using `$html = file_get_html("http://www.google.com/");`

If I `print_r($html)` at this point I get :

```
simple_html_dom Object
(
    [root:simple_html_dom:private] => simple_html_dom_node Object
        (
            [nodetype] => 5
            [tag:simple_html_dom_node:private] => text
            [attr:simple_html_dom_node:private] => Array
                (
                    [tag] => root
                )
            [children:simple_html_dom_node:private] => simple_html_dom_node Object
                (
                    [nodetype] => 1
                    [tag:simple_html_dom_node:private] => html
                    [attr:simple_html_dom_node:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [children:simple_html_dom_node:private] => simple_html_dom_node Object
                           (
                                [nodetype] => 1
                                [tag:simple_html_dom_node:private] => head
                                [attr:simple_html_dom_node:private] => Array
                           (
                            )...
```

Then if I try $html->find('a',0), $html->find('a') or even something like $html->find('head'), and print the result, I always get an empty Array.

```
class Product extends Stackable{
    function __construct($prod_id,$link)
    {
        $this->prod_id=$prod_id;
        $this->link=$link;
    }

    public function get_data($country)
    {
        //AMAZON API XML REQUEST
        return $xml; //XML file
    }

    public function parse_data($xml)
    {
        $product = array();
       //PARSE PRODUCT XML INTO ARRAY
        return $product; 
    }

    public function update_price($product)
    {
        $html = file_get_html($this->link);
        print_r ($html->find('a'));
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $xml = $this->get_data('US');
        $product = $this->parse_data($xml);
        $this->update_price($product);
    }
}

$product = new Product(ID,URL);
$worker = new Worker();
$worker->start();
$worker->stack($product);
```

What could be the issue?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: show the actual code ...

Comment: @JoeWatkins, I've provided a summary of the code in question, though i tried to still keep is a minimal as possible since there is a lot which i don't think would be relevant to the issue

Comment: I cannot see the problem there, but I have a feeling at some point you write the HTML object to the Stackable object, if the object doesn't serialize gracefully you will get strange behaviour, do not write it to the Stackable object until it's prepared for sharing, an HTML object is not prepared for sharing and should not be written to the Stackable scope and relied upon.

Comment: @JoeWatkins, I believe I figured it out. If I've understood correctly, pthreads is not a big fan of `public` variables correct? I rewrote the simple_html_dom source code to convert any reference of `public` to `private` to make sure there weren't any messiness between threads.

Comment: everything is considered public

Comment: it is not a fan of [some] complex objects external to pthreads being used as members because they do not lend themselves to being stored how pthreads stores members, if an object is corrupted after being retrieved from the object scope this is usually the culprit - it doesn't serialize/unserialize gracefully/correctly

Comment: Alright thanks, so does this mean that if the object is created by the thread there shouldn't be any issues?